# how many times we should used ford-Fulkerson?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

We given a network with `K` vertexes and give `a` and `b`. capacity of all edges is `infinite`. for a flow from `a` to `b`, the edge that pass `max flow` through it, called bottleneck edge and capacity of transferred flow through that edge is called bottleneck of flow. an integer `M` is given. we want transfer flow with size `M` with lowest bottleneck from a to b. how many times we should used ford-Fulkerson to calculate this flow?

O(1) runs is the answer, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you assign each edge a capacity 1, run FF a single time, and get the resulting graph. Moreover, let the max flow be *M'*. Intuitively, we find that the min cut is $M'$, meaning that there are *M'* edge-disjoint paths from a to b in this case. This tells us how to get to a solution of *⌈ M / M' ⌉*, by scaling the flows appropriately. For example, suppose that $M=5$, and when setting the capacities to 1, we get $M' = 2$. Then we know that the min-cut is 2. If we increase the capacity to 5 / 2 = 2.5, then we would get exactly the flow of 5 to begin with. Since this is a non-integer, we would increase the capacity of some edges (forming a path from a to b) to 3, and some to 2.

You cannot get anything lower than what was just found. If you could get something lower, say *M'' < ⌈ M / M' ⌉*, then if you would set the capacity of all edges to *M''*, the flow would not change. By the max-flow / min-cut theorem, this means that there is a min-cut of *M / M'' > M'* edges. This contradicts the min cut being only *M'*.

Comment: nice algorithm +1. what is the role of scaling the flows means intuitively in simple words for this question?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify some points. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MK If M=10 and M'=5, then the scaling is 2, as you state. The bottleneck in this case is 2. Not sure what you're asking me to correct.

Comment: @MK If the M = 10, and M' = 2, then the bottleneck is 5, and there are 2 edge-disjoint paths from a to b. If you scale the capacity of all edges to 5, then each path gives 5, and the overall flow is 10, which is exactly M.